# how to reference LinkedList inside of itself

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

i am trying to sort a LinkedList by filling a new temporary list.
it works fine - the 'tempList' is sorted correct - but how can i reference the actual list inside of it self?

```
public class LinkedList implements AbstractListType {

    public void addSorted(Object data){
        /* */
    }

    public void sort(){
        Node runpointer = first;
        AbstractListType tempList = new LinkedList();

        while(runpointer.next != null){
            tempList.addSorted(runpointer.data);
            runpointer = runpointer.next;
        }
    // tempList == this list //
    }
```

Comment: "how can i reference the actual list inside of it self?" Unclear, please rephrase.

Comment: i create the list 'list  in my main function. then call list.sort(). inside the sort function i create the tempList that gets sorted. how can i make list equal tempList

Comment: And? Do you pass it into your sort function? Or, is it a static field?

Comment: The simple answer to "how do you reference itself" is `this`, but it seems like that's not what you really want to ask. Your posted code seems to be asking, "how do I assign a different value to myself?", which is impossible or meaningless by definition, so you need to think of a slightly different way to accomplish what you want to do. You can't assign to `this`, but you can assign to any non-final fields you might have.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LinkedList implements AbstractListType {

public void addSorted(Object data){
    /* */
}

public void sort(){
    Node runpointer = first;
    AbstractListType tempList = new LinkedList();

    while(runpointer.next != null){
        tempList.addSorted(runpointer.data);
        runpointer = runpointer.next;
    }
   runpointer.head = tempList.head;   // now your runpointer has the same list in the tempList
}
```